# GroupBy with elementSelector and resultSelector

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The `Enumerable.GroupBy` and `Queryable.GroupBy` extensions have 8 overloads. Two of them (for `Enumerable.GroupBy`) are:

```
// (a)
IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector);

// (b)
IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector,
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult> resultSelector);
```

(for `Queryable.GroupBy` the same, just with `Expression<Func<...` instead of `Func<...`)

`(b)` has an additional `elementSelector` as parameter.

On MSDN is [an example for overload (a)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx) and [an example for overload (b)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534493.aspx). They both work with the same example source collection:

```
List<Pet> petsList = new List<Pet>
{
    new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8.3 },
    new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4.9 },
    new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1.5 },
    new Pet { Name="Daisy", Age=4.3 }
};
```

Example (a) uses this query:

```
var query = petsList.GroupBy(
    pet => Math.Floor(pet.Age), // keySelector
    (age, pets) => new          // resultSelector
    {
        Key = age,
        Count = pets.Count(),
        Min = pets.Min(pet => pet.Age),
        Max = pets.Max(pet => pet.Age)
    });
```

And example (b) uses this query:

```
var query = petsList.GroupBy(
    pet => Math.Floor(pet.Age), // keySelector
    pet => pet.Age,             // elementSelector
    (baseAge, ages) => new      // resultSelector
    {
        Key = baseAge,
        Count = ages.Count(),
        Min = ages.Min(),
        Max = ages.Max()
    });
```

The result of both queries is exactly the same.

Question 1: Is there any kind of query that I cannot express by using the `resultSelector` alone and where I really would need the `elementSelector`? Or are the capabilities of the two overloads always equivalent and it is just a matter of taste to use one or the other way?

Question 2: Is there a counterpart for the two different overloads when using LINQ query syntax?

(As a side question: When using `Queryable.GroupBy` with Entity Framework, will both overloads be translated into the exact same SQL?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For IEnumerable:

```
petsList.GroupBy(
    pet => Math.Floor(pet.Age), // keySelector
    (age, pets) => new          // resultSelector
    {
        Key = age,
        Count = pets.Count(),
        Min = pets.Min(pet => pet.Age),
        Max = pets.Max(pet => pet.Age)
    });
```

is equevalent to:

```
var query = petsList.GroupBy(
    pet => Math.Floor(pet.Age), // keySelector
    pet => pet,             // elementSelector
    (baseAge, ages) => new      // resultSelector
    {
        Key = baseAge,
        Count = ages.Count(),
        Min = ages.Min(pet => pet.Age),
        Max = ages.Max(pet => pet.Age)
    });
```

using of elementSelector could simplifies expressions in resultSelector (compare next and previous):

```
var query = petsList.GroupBy(
    pet => Math.Floor(pet.Age), // keySelector
    pet => pet.Age,             // elementSelector
    (baseAge, ages) => new      // resultSelector
    {
        Key = baseAge,
        Count = ages.Count(),
        Min = ages.Min(), //there is no lambda due to element selector
        Max = ages.Max() ////there is no lambda due to element selector
    });
```

In IQueryable, it is not so simple. You can look at sources of this methods:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, Expression<Func<TSource, TElement>> elementSelector, Expression<Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult>> resultSelector)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("source"); 
            if (keySelector == null)
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector"); 
            if (elementSelector == null) 
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("elementSelector");
            if (resultSelector == null) 
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("resultSelector");
            return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(
                Expression.Call(
                    null, 
                    ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), typeof(TKey), typeof(TElement), typeof(TResult)),
                    new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(keySelector), Expression.Quote(elementSelector), Expression.Quote(resultSelector) } 
                    )); 
        }

public static IQueryable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,Expression<Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult>> resultSelector)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("source"); 
            if (keySelector == null)
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector"); 
            if (resultSelector == null) 
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("resultSelector");
            return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>( 
                Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), typeof(TKey), typeof(TResult)),
                    new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote(keySelector), Expression.Quote(resultSelector) } 
                    ));
        }
```

As you can see, they returns different expressions, so I'm not sure that result SQL query will be same in all cases, but i *suppose* that SQL query for overload with elementSelector + resultSelector will be not slower compare to overload without elementSelector.

Answer 1: No, for IEnumerable there is no query that you cannot express by using the `resultSelector` alone.

Answer 2. No, there are no counterpart for the two different overloads when using LINQ query syntax. Extension methods have more possibilities compare to LINQ query syntax.

Answer 3 (For side question): it is not guaranteed that sql queries will be same for this overloads.